# HPA not able to fetch metrics from Prometheus in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, prometheus

I have a two node Kubernetes cluster i.e one master node and two worker nodes. For monitoring purpose, I have deployed Prometheus and Grafana. Now, I want to autoscale pods based on CPU usage. But even after configuring Grafana and Prometheus, I am getting the following error ---

```
Name:                                                  php-apache
Namespace:                                             default
Labels:                                                <none>
Annotations:                                           <none>
CreationTimestamp:                                     Mon, 17 Jun 2019 12:33:01 +0530
Reference:                                             Deployment/php-apache
Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  <unknown> / 50%
Min replicas:                                          1
Max replicas:                                          10
Deployment pods:                                       1 current / 0 desired
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason                   Message
  ----           ------  ------                   -------
  AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetResourceMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
Events:
  Type     Reason                   Age                      From                       Message
  ----     ------                   ----                     ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetResourceMetric  112s (x12408 over 2d4h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metrics for resource cpu: unable to fetch metrics from resource metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)
```

Can anybody let me know why Kubernetes is not fetching metrics from Prometheus ?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes retrieves metrics from either the `metrics.k8s.io` API (normally implemented by the `metrics-server` which can be seperatly installed) or the `custom.metrics.k8s.io` API (which can be any type of metric and is normally provided by third parties). To use prometheus in HPA for kubernetes the [Prometheus Adapter](https://github.com/directxman12/k8s-prometheus-adapter) for the custom metrics API needs to be installed.

A walkthrough for the setup can be found [here](https://github.com/DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapter/blob/master/docs/walkthrough.md).

Comment: I am not using https here. I learnt that in order to use custom metrics, we have to first configure a Aggregator and then register custom metrics APIs such as the Prometheus Adapter to it. Do we then need self signed certificates to configure Aggregator ?

Answer (score 1):

heapster is now depracted : https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/heapster

To enable auto-scaling on your cluster you can use HPA(horizontal pod auto-scaler) and you can also install metrics server to check all metrics.

To install metrics server on kubernetes you can follow this guide also :

```
amazon : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/metrics-server.html
https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server
https://medium.com/@cagri.ersen/kubernetes-metrics-server-installation-d93380de008
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need custom metrics to use HPA for auto-scaling pods based on their CPU usage.

As @Blokje5 mentioned earlier, you just need to install 'kube-state-metrics'.

The most convenient way to do it is with a dedicated helm chart ([kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/kube-state-metrics)).

**Hint:** use override parameters with 'helm install' to create ServiceMonitor object for 'kube-state-metrics' Pod, to allow Prometheus to discover a new target for metrics scraping, e.g.:

```
helm install stable/kube-state-metrics --set prometheus.monitor.enabled=true
```

**Remark:** Pay attention to the 'serviceMonitorSelector' defined in your existing Prometheus resource object/configuration, so that it matches the ServiceMonitor definition for 'kube-state-metrics'. This is to make available Pods' metrics in Prometheus console.